# Error Trying to Use Temporary Columns, mysql

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error,

`#1054 - Unknown column 'finalResult' in 'field list'`

when ever I run this mysql query

```
SELECT userID, pickID, nflp_picks.gameID, visitorID, visitorResult, homeID, homeResult,

IF (pickID=visitorID, visitorResult, homeResult) AS finalResult,

IF (finalResult="Winner", 1, 0) AS Win

FROM nflp_picks, nflp_schedule

WHERE nflp_picks.gameID = nflp_schedule.gameID

ORDER BY gameID, pickID, userID

LIMIT 0, 200
```

Can I not use temporary columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't refer to aliases in the same query, except in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, and HAVING clauses. You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT *, (finalResult = "Winner") AS Win
FROM (SELECT userID, pickID, nflp_picks.gameID, visitorID, visitorResult, homeID, homeResult,
             IF (pickID=visitorID, visitorResult, homeResult) AS finalResult
      FROM nflp_picks
      JOIN nflp_schedule
      ON nflp_picks.gameID = nflp_schedule.gameID
      ORDER BY gameID, pickID, userID
      LIMIT 0, 200) x
```

Comment: If I want to achieve something like 

(finalResult = "Winner", 1, 0) AS Win
(finalResult = "Loser", 1, 0) AS Lost
(finalResult = "Push", 1, 0) AS Push

How would I do that?

Comment: Figured it out, Thanks!